# Create OpenGL matrices from affine camera matrix

Tags: opengl, computer-vision, rendering, camera-calibration

I have a set of 2D to 3D point correspondences, and I estimate an affine camera matrix from these correspondences (basically, assuming an orthographic projection)[1]. The output of the camera estimation is a `3x4` matrix where the third row is `[0, 0, 0, 1]` (the "affine constraint").

Now from this camera matrix, I'd like to render my model using OpenGL. So in essence, create a `ModelView` and an (orthographic) `Projection` matrix from the camera matrix I have.

I've read hours of material on camera matrix dissection/decomposition, but all of it is about **perspective** cameras, and as the "z" information is missing in my matrix, I could not apply these techniques.

I've tried numerous attempts, most of which failed at a very early stage. One thing I tried was taking the dot product of the first and second row of the matrix (without the last column of course) to create a new row which transforms `z`, but it's just `[0, 0, 1]`, which of course makes sense.
Another thing I tried was converting my 2D points to clip coordinate space (i.e. "reversing" the window transform) before estimating the camera matrix, so I can take the window transform and flipping y (in my screen space, the origin is on the upper-left) out of the picture.

I'm frankly at a loss on how to fundamentally approach this problem.

[1]: *Gold Standard Algorithm for estimating an affine camera matrix from world to image correspondences, Algorithm 7.2 in Multiple View Geometry, Hartley & Zisserman, 2nd Edition, 2003.*

Answer (score 0):

The affine camera (see e.g. [here](http://math.umn.edu/~poli0048/CameraModels.pdf)) just performs an ortho projection followed by an affine warp.

Given than one can always use an OpenGL orthographic camera as a rasterization device for arbitrary image transformation, an affine camera can be emulated as follows:

1. Create an orthographic camera for the scene. Render the scene
   using it, read back the generated image.
2. Apply the affine transform induced by the camera model on this image, by pushing said affine transform as a texture transformation matrix.
3. Render a rectangle in front of the ortho camera (a "card") covering its field of view, and texture said rectangle with the image produced in step 1. It will be warped using the affine transform as requested.

This sequence can be optimized if performance is an issue. Read on "render to texture" for how.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question. After estimating the affine camera from let's say 5 points, I have a full 3D model that I want to render using said camera matrix and OpenGL. I don't think I want to warp my image - I want to render my model.

Comment: Please clarify what is your "model": a mesh of your triangulated 3D points, with topology built by Delaunay triangulation in one view?

Comment: Yep, it's a normal 3D mesh, as you encounter it in a game engine. A cube consisting of triangles if you wish.

Comment: Edited answer to clarify.

Comment: Take a look here http://ksimek.github.io/2013/06/03/calibrated_cameras_in_opengl/